# integration of different features into controller code

Tags: opendaylight

I have downloaded the source code of OpenDaylight controller from https://github.com/opendaylight/controller/releases. I want to add/integrate openflowplugin or l2switch features into the controller code. How do I enable any feature within source based opendaylight controller code (e.g. controller-release-boron-sr3). I can separately build openflowplugin code and controller code but I would like to integrate the two. Any help is highly appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

When you build openflowplugin, it will automatically bring in all of it's
dependencies. the controller project is a dependency of openflowplugin so
you get it for free. Similarly, if you build the l2switch project, you will
get it's dependencies which is openflowplugin thus controller as well.

Also, if you build the integration/distribution project you will get
everything from all OpenDaylight projects as it's the top level project
that brings everything together for the main release.